# Counting distinct values in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have this postgresql query:

```
    SELECT
    fato_pedido_promob.id_pedido_promob,
    dim_tempo.data,
    fato_pedido_promob.valor_total_pedido,
    dim_cliente_promob.cpf_cnpj,
    dim_cliente_promob.email,
    dim_cliente_promob.segmento,
    dim_cliente_promob.razao_social,
    data_ultimo_pedido,
    extract(day from current_date::timestamp - data_ultimo_pedido::timestamp) as dias_ultimo_pedido,
    count(fato_pedido_promob.id_pedido_promob) as pedidos_por_cpf
    
FROM
    dim_cliente_promob
LEFT JOIN
    fato_pedido_promob ON dim_cliente_promob.id_cliente = fato_pedido_promob.fk_cliente_promob
LEFT JOIN
            dim_tempo ON dim_tempo.id_tempo = fato_pedido_promob.fk_data_emissao
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            cpf_cnpj,
            MAX(dim_tempo.data) AS data_ultimo_pedido
        FROM
            dim_cliente_promob
        LEFT JOIN
            fato_pedido_promob ON dim_cliente_promob.id_cliente = fato_pedido_promob.fk_cliente_promob
        LEFT JOIN
            dim_tempo ON dim_tempo.id_tempo = fato_pedido_promob.fk_data_emissao
        WHERE
            cpf_cnpj <> 'Desconhecido'
            AND id_pedido_promob IS NOT NULL
            AND dim_tempo.data < CURRENT_DATE
        GROUP BY
            cpf_cnpj
    ) AS max_data ON dim_cliente_promob.cpf_cnpj = max_data.cpf_cnpj
WHERE
    dim_cliente_promob.cpf_cnpj <> 'Desconhecido'
    AND id_pedido_promob IS NOT NULL
    AND data < CURRENT_DATE 
GROUP BY    
    dim_cliente_promob.cpf_cnpj,
    fato_pedido_promob.id_pedido_promob,
    dim_tempo.data,
    fato_pedido_promob.valor_total_pedido,
    dim_cliente_promob.email,
    dim_cliente_promob.segmento,
    dim_cliente_promob.razao_social,
    data_ultimo_pedido,
    
    

ORDER BY
    data DESC;
```

the `customer id = dim_cliente_promob.cpf_cnpj`

the `order id = fato_pedido_promob.id_pedido_promob`

I need to count how many order id's per customer.

I've tried `count(fato_pedido_promob.id_pedido_promob) as pedidos_por_cpf`, but it only returns the `value = 1` for all the customers.

Any ideas on how I might be messing it up?

Comment: Why do you have so many `GROUP BY` clauses?

Comment: This calculated row: extract(day from current_date::timestamp - data_ultimo_pedido::timestamp) as dias_ultimo_pedido, needs a groupby inside a subquery because it calculates the date of the last order. and it groups by customer id.

The second groupby is for the next calculated field: count(fato_pedido_promob.id_pedido_promob) as pedidos_por_cpf

Comment: I don't mean why you have two `GROUP BY`s, but why there are so many expressions in the second one. If you want to count per customer, then you should only group by the customer id and nothing else

Comment: If i put only customer id, postgresql returns an error like:

ERROR:  column "dim_cliente_promob.razao_social" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 10:     dim_cliente_promob.razao_social,

Answer (score 0):

You need a window function:

```
count(fato_pedido_promob.id_pedido_promob) OVER (PARTITION BY dim_cliente_promob.cpf_cnpj)
```

However, you won't be able to eliminate duplicates that way.